# How are Star Trek medical devices attached to the neck?

Tags: effects, star-trek, make-up, star-trek-voyager

In Star Trek Voyager, it happens a few times that a medical device is attached to the neck. For example, in S03E02 "Flashback" at 8:28, the doctor attaches a device to Tuvok's neck. Attaching that device takes about 1 second. It sticks instantly.

How does this work out of universe? How does the production crew make it happen that the prop sticks live during the shot? It can't be glue because it sticks right away.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Double-sided tape, already applied to the face of the prop, sticks to the actor long enough to get the shot; then if they need more resilience for subsequent shots, props/make-up can stick it more firmly using a type of ['rubber' glue](https://camerareadycosmetics.com/collections/sfx-makeup/adhesive), also used for prosthetics.

I'm not sure whether people tend to use just whatever double-sided tape they can find at the local stationer's or whether they go all-out for specialist tape like [Joe's Sticky Stuff](https://www.joeprops.com/what-is-it).
As mentioned on that site, the alternative is [butyl tape](https://www.filmtools.com/butyl.html), but you wouldn't want that on your skin. [Anecdotally, I've never heard anyone actually call it 'butyl'; they tend to call it 'black tack' or 'tacky tack'.]